# Traveling to France with prescripton medications

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, france, health, paperwork

I take several medications for my fibromylgia and arthritis all are prescription drugs. Will I need any documentation from my doctor? A couple of these are classed narcotics.

Comment: There's a dedicated page about medication transportation in France on the official french custom site : http://www.douane.gouv.fr/articles/a11946-le-transport-de-medicaments-en-france-par-des-particuliers . It is unfortunately not available in english. Nevertheless, the rules generally are : you need to be able to produce the prescription and the quantity you carry should be adequate with the prescription or with a 3 month treatment. rules vary slightly depending if you come from Schengen area or not.

Answer (score 4):

### Flying into France with Prescription Medicines (Importing Them)

[The official French customs website has a dedicated page (in French) on importing prescription medications for personal use into France.](http://www.douane.gouv.fr/articles/a11946-le-transport-de-medicaments-en-france-par-des-particuliers) The page has subsequently been [made available in English](http://www.douane.gouv.fr/articles/a13412-private-individuals-carrying-medicinal-products-in-france). Some of the rules are dependant on whether passengers are coming from inside the Schengen area or not. I will paraphrase (and quote) the French version below.

#### Personal-Use Quantities Are Limited by Treatment Duration

The general rule says that passengers are allowed to carry exactly the amount of personal-use medication they need for the treatment, no more no less. The duration of the treatment will be indicated on the prescription. If not, a fixed three month period will be taken into account.

> L'usage personnel correspond soit à la durée de traitement prévue par l'ordonnance médicale, soit, à défaut d'ordonnance, à une durée de traitement de trois mois.

If passengers carry more then none of the medicines will be allowed inside France:

> Avertissement : si les quantités transportées excèdent l'usage personnel, l'importation est prohibée à titre absolu.

#### Narcotics/Psychotropic Drugs Need a Prescription and a Transport Certificate

However, in the case of prescription narcotics or psychotropic drugs, a prescription from your doctor is mandatory as well as a transport certificate/authorisation delivered by the regulatory body of the country/region in which the drug was prescribed. This is true for both intra-Schengen as well as extra-Schengen flights.

> ### En provenance d'un pays membre de l'espace Schengen
>
> [...]
>
> #### Médicament stupéfiant ou psychotrope
>
> - **Principe** : la quantité transportée est en relation avec un usage personnel.
> - **Justificatif** à présenter à la douane : le certificat délivré par les autorités compétentes du pays de provenance est obligatoire. 
>         *A l'expédition vers un pays membre de l'espace Schengen, le particulier résidant en France doit pouvoir produire l'original de la prescription ainsi qu'une autorisation de transport délivrée par l'agence régionale de santé auprès de laquelle le médecin prescripteur est enregistré. Cette autorisation est valable trente jours dans la limite de la durée maximale de prescription du médicament transporté.*
>
> [...]
>
> ### En provenance d'un pays non membre de l'espace Schengen
>
> [...]
>
> #### Médicament stupéfiant ou psychotrope
>
> - **Principe** : la quantité transportée correspond à la durée du traitement.
> - **Justificatif** à présenter à la douane : l'ordonnance du médecin dont la production est obligatoire. 
>     *A l'exportation vers un pays non membre de l'espace Schengen, le particulier doit pouvoir produire l'original de la prescription médicale. Toutefois, à compter du 1er août 2015, pour les médicaments classés comme stupéfiants, l'Agence nationale de sécurité du médicament et des produits de santé (ANSM) délivrera des attestations de transport uniquement si le pays de destination exige, pour l'entrée sur son territoire, un certificat des autorités compétentes du pays de résidence du patient. Ces attestations seront délivrées pour des quantités transportées correspondant à une durée de traitement ne dépassant pas la durée maximale de prescription autorisée (attestation de transport délivrée par le département stupéfiants/psychotropes de l'Agence nationale de sécurité du médicament et des produits de santé).*

Although the prescription might not be mandatory in all cases, I would advise you to carry it, along with as much documentation as possible to prove that the medicines/narcotics are for your personal use.