# Medication for ADHD

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, france, drugs

My boyfriend, son and I are planning to go to France in July 2018. My son is on ADHD medication and my boyfriend takes anxiety medicine.
Do we need transport certificates/authorization forms for those medications and if so, where do I get those?

Comment: What are the specific medications?

Comment: If this is prescription medicine, general rules are that a) you keep the medication in the original container and have a copy of prescription (unless printed on a container itself) and b) declare it to the Customs. Note that still some medicine might not be allowed through.

Comment: Related, with useful links, but not quite a duplicate: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/57056/19400

Comment: What is your nationality and where do you fly from? (Not always important but it can make a difference.)

Answer (score 1):

[France’s Customs web site](http://www.douane.gouv.fr/articles/a13412-private-individuals-carrying-medicinal-products-in-france) gives the details you need:

> **Private individuals carrying medicinal products in France**
>
> The quantity of medicinal products you may carry must not exceed the quantity required for personal use.
>
> - **General information**
>
> You carry medicinal products with you when you travel. The customs authorities help to ensure compliance with the regulations.
>
> **Warning: if the quantities carried exceed those required for personal use, importation is strictly prohibited.**
>
> Personal use corresponds to the length of treatment specified by the medical prescription or, where there is none, treatment for three months.
>
> - **What is the definition of a medicinal product?**
>
> Article L 5111-1 of the French Public Health Code defines a medicinal product as « any substance or combination of substances presented as possessing curative or preventive properties with regard to human or animal diseases » (medical product by presentation) and « any substance or combination of substances that may be used in or administered to humans or animals in order to make a medical diagnosis or to restore, correct or modify their physiological functions by exerting a pharmacological, immunological or metabolic action » (medical product by function).
>
> - **What are the rules governing the importation into France of medicinal
>     products by a private individual?**
>
> Where the medicinal products are carried by the traveller him/herself for personal use, the conditions for importation are as follows.
>
> **Non-narcotic and non-psychotropic medicinal products**
>
> General rule for individuals from all countries:
>
> - **Principle:** the quantity carried corresponds to the length of treatment given on the prescription or, if there is none, treatment for three months.
> - **Supporting document to produce for customs:** the doctor’s prescription, production of which is not mandatory unless the length of treatment exceeds three months.
>
> **Narcotic drug or psychotropic substance**
>
> **Private individuals may import narcotic drugs or psychotropic substances only if they carry them personally.**
>
> **The quantities carried must be compatible with personal therapeutic use for the length of treatment given on the prescription or, where there is none, treatment for one month under normal conditions of use.**
>
> Article 75 of the Convention implementing the Schengen Agreement of 14 June 1985 stipulates the applicable regulations according to the country of origin.
>
> From a Schengen area member state
>
> - **Principle:** the quantity transported is compatible with personal therapeutic use.
> - **Supporting document to produce for customs:** the certificate issued by the competent authorities of the country of origin is mandatory.
>
> From a country that is not a Schengen area member state
>
> - **Principle:** the quantity transported is compatible with personal therapeutic use.
> - **Supporting document to produce for customs:** the doctor’s prescription, production of which is mandatory.

Comment: Is there a definition of "psychotropic" and "narcotic"?  ADHD is often treated with stimulants that are highly controlled in, e.g., the US, but I don't know whether they are included in either of these categories by France.

Comment: @phoog There is no definition of narcotic drug or psychotropic substance in the relevant regulation. With psychotropic meaning 'mood altering', it is likely that both ADHD and anxiety medication is psychotropic.